# 'Catel.IoC.IServiceLocator' does not contain a definition for 'Instance'

Tags: c#, catel, memento

I'm quite new to .NET development and Catel but is working on a project to learn it. At the moment the original developer is not present so I'll try my luck here instead.

To implement Undo/Redo the Memento Pattern support of Catel seems great so giving it a try but I have problems getting an instance of the MementoService. When I do in my ViewModel:

`var mementoService = ServiceLocator.Instance.ResolveType<IMementoService>();`

I get:

`'Catel.IoC.IServiceLocator' does not contain a definition for 'Instance' and no extension method 'Instance' accepting a first argument of type 'Catel.IoC.IServiceLocator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I have noticed that when I do the same in my Model though I do not get this problem. Seems strange that I would need different ways of getting an instance of the service depending on where I try to get it.

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. The NuGet Package Manager Console tells me I have Catel.Extensions.Memento 3.7 installed as well as Catel.Core, Catel.MVVM and Catel.Extensions.Controls 3.7. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with .NET 4.0.

Comment: I know nothing of Catel but if you go in the class where it works and you hit F12 on `Instance` where does it bring you? Perhaps it's an extension method and you're only missing a `using`.

Comment: It is part of Catel.IoC and added <code>using Catel.IoC;</code> to my ViewModel which did not help. Thanks for the suggestion eventhough it didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface does not have an *Instance* property, and it is obsolete.

You should use this:

1) In a static context:

Catel.IoC.ServiceLocator.Default

2) In a non-static context (takes care of scopes automatically):

var serviceLocator = this.GetServiceLocator();

Comment: Thanks! Would be great if the documentation included this.

Comment: It is documented, but a bit deep in the docs: https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Introduction+to+DependencyResolver+and+DependencyResolverManager

Comment: I was only looking at the Memento documentation https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Memento+and+collections since I was adding Undo/Redo functionality for a Collection. None of the example code use the GetServiceLocator() method and as you see it also lists the obsolete Instance property.

Comment: The advantage of Confluence (the wiki) is that you can customize the doc and help us maintain it ;-)

Comment: I tried to find some edit but couldn't :( Not familiar with Confluence but will give it another try.

Comment: Guess I dont have Edit Permissions https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF35/Editing+an+Existing+Page

My profile https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/~kalle

Comment: Nothing happens when I press 'e' and there are not Edit or similar in any menues :(

Comment: Please contact us via http://catelproject.com/support/contact-us/ so we can discuss this further.